# CSS mouse hover glows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone tell me this effect used in this page (https://www.canva.com/)
When you hover a region, it's glows. I need a name of this effect to find a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This effect is very special and I don't thing that there are any tutorials out there. Anyway, creating things like that is really not easy and maybe you should get an advanced understanding of web development first in order to really understand the code and what it does in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the JS file: https://static.canva.com/static/r/woopwoop/js/XIR9abnkRmmIBfD9RiiwSg.js

The CSS file: https://static.canva.com/static/r/woopwoop/css/auth/YC3uEEMWOOxOK1-4GWZMtQ.css

And this bit of code: `<canvas class="loginFun" width="320" height="700"></canvas>`

Comment: Try using your browser's developer tools to remove the background image of the <body> tag. The blurry photo will disappear. You'll see that there is another canvas which is painting the same photo without blur. Maybe the talented developers at Canva are using a pattern-based brush like this one — https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/DLamu — discussed here: http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/.